Struggle with geometry problem
The problem goes:

Let $C$ a circle $C_1$ and $C_2$ two circles internally tangents to $C$ at $P$ and $Q$ respectively. $C_1$ and $C_2$ also are externally tangents to each other at $T$. Show that the perpendicular to $\overline{PT}$ passing by $P$ cross $\overline{QT}$ on $C$.

So I had 3 possibilities that I tried:
First, I thought about cyclic quadrilateral so let $K$ be the second intersection of $\overline{PT}$ and $C$, $A$ is the intersection of the perpendicular to $\overline{PT}$ and $\overline{QT}$. I tried to show that $APQK$ is a cyclic quadrilateral but with only the fact that $\measuredangle APK = 90^\circ$. I didn't find anything conclusive. I tried proving that $\measuredangle AQK = 90^\circ$ but didn't succeed.
Secondly, I thought of power of a point which looks good for this kind of problem but I really don't see what point could be interesting to calculate its power. I tried with $T$ but it didn't work.
The last thing I tried was to use the property of Thales's circle as $\triangle APK$ is a right triangle to prove that $\triangle AQK$ also was one (we come back to the first point).
How to do this problem?

Can you add an image through here?

Please, use descriptive titles. "Struggle with problem" says nothing about the subject of the question.

I've rolled the question back to a state that includes the actual problem statement. (Without it, the answers don't make any sense ... nor do the "possibilities" discussed, for that matter.)

Doesn't the problem have sufficient amount of details? And is it not crystal clear? Why is it closed all of a sudden?

This is indeed a very tricky problem. The simplest solution is to invert with respect to $P$ with radius $1$ (any radius works.)
If $A$ is an object in the plane, let $A^*$ denote the object obtained after inversion.
The inverted figure
$C^*$ and $C^*_1$ become parallel lines. $C^*_2$ becomes the circle tangent to the lines $C^*$ and $C^*_1$ at $Q^*$ and $T^*$. Let the line perpendicular to $PT^*$ intersect $C^*$ at $A^*$.
Finishing the problem
If we can show that $A^*, P, Q^*, T^*$ is cyclic, we are done. This is trivial as $\angle A^*PT^*=\angle AQ^*T^*=90^\circ$. QED
Comments on this question
The reason I have inverted is because there are so many circles. If you want to read more about inversion, see the Wikipedia page for reference. It is going to be an absolute pain not doing this question with inversion.
The diagram for the inverted figure

In the figure, the symbol $*$ for inversion has been ignored. So just add a $*$ to all the characters in the diagram, apart from $P$ ofcourse.

$APQT$ isn't cyclic on the original diagram is it normal ? Also I would I thought that  $C$ and $C_2$ would be in reverse order am i wrong ?

$APQT$ is indeed not cyclic on the original figure. However $A,Q,T$ are collinear. When we invert w.r.t $P$, this line becomes a circle through $P$. Note this is inversion, not reflection.


The solution given below makes use of the well-known fact that the three common tangents of three mutually tangential circles meet at a point. We need to draw the auxiliary line segment $PQ$, which is a chord of the circle $c_0$, to facilitate some angle chasing required for our proof. As shown in the diagram, for brevity, we let $\measuredangle PTR = \alpha$ and $\measuredangle RTQ = \omega$, where $R$ is the point common to the three tangents.
Since all three common tangents are equal in length, $\triangle TRP$ and $\triangle QRT$ are isosceles. Therefore, we have,
$$\measuredangle TRP=180-2\alpha \quad\text{and}\quad \measuredangle QRT=180-2\omega.$$
It follows,
$$\measuredangle QRP=\measuredangle TRP+\measuredangle QRT= 360-2\alpha -2\omega.\tag{1}$$
The quadrilateral $QRPO_0$ is cyclic. Hence, according to (1), we have,
$$\measuredangle PO_0Q=2\alpha+2\omega-180. \tag{2}$$
Furthermore, note that,
$$\measuredangle STP=180-\measuredangle PTR - \measuredangle RTQ = 180 - \alpha- \omega.$$
Since $\triangle STP$ is right-angled, we shall write,
$$\measuredangle PST =180 - \measuredangle STP - \measuredangle TPS = 180 -\left(180 - \alpha- \omega\right) – 90 = \alpha + \omega -90.\tag{3}$$
When we compare (2) and (3), we see that,
$$\measuredangle PO_0Q = 2\times \measuredangle PST = 2\times \measuredangle PSQ.$$
Hence, according to Euclid III 20, the point of intersection of the perpendicular to $PT$ at $P$ and extended $QT$ (i.e., point $S$) must lie on the circumference of the circle that has its center at $O_0$ and passes through $P$ and $Q$. This circle is none other than $c_0$.
